# IIS Request Filtering blocks Application Request Routing

Tags: iis, trac, arr, request-filtering

Using one box, I have an IIS server and a [tracd](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracStandalone) server running. Via ARR, any request on the IIS server matching */trac/** is proxied through to the tracd server.

Everything is working fine, except when a user requests something like */trac/Test/browser/trunk/Test.cs*. Because requests for .cs file extensions are blocked by the IIS server, the request never makes it to the tracd server and the user gets a 404.

Is there any way to add an exception to Request Filtering that allows **all** requests matching */trac/**? This would effectivly delegate Request Filtering to the target server farm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I added the following to my `applicationHost.config`.

```
<location path="Default Web Site/trac">
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions>
          <clear />
        </fileExtensions>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <clear />
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```